# AtomicLong possible race condition?

Tags: java, atomic

I know that a possible race condition is Read-Modify-Write, an example:

```
public class UnsafeSequence {
     private int value;
     public int getNext(){
          value = value + 1;
          return value;
     }
}
```

In my code I use AtomicLong:

```
public class Test {
      private AtomicLong size = new AtomicLong();

      public void test(Object myPersonalObject){
           //do something

           this.size.set(this.size.get() + myPersonalObject.getSize().get());


           //do something
      }
}
```

the `myPersonalObject.getSize()` return an AtomicLong.

The question is: this instructions `this.size.set(this.size.get() + myPersonalObject.getSize().get());` can generate a race condition?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't use `size.addAndGet(myPersonalObject.getSize().get())`?

Comment: sure it can generate, atomic is not a synonymous for synchronized

Comment: I could use it, but I want refresh only the size of class Test. The value returned by `size.addAndGet(...)` will lost because I don't need it.

Comment: So what if it gets "lost"? It's just a return value you don't use, it won't get angry at you.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman for help me... I think there was a way or a method for only add a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `this.size.set(this.size.get() + myPersonalObject.getSize().get());` is nowhere near an atomic operation, even if you're using atomic components.

When you've performed `size.get()` and you start to add it with `myPersonalObject.getSize().get()` the original value of `size` can be changed.

Assigning the value of computation back to `size` makes the change disappear. It would be somewhat similar to this single threaded code

```
int size = 2;
int myObj = 3;
int temp = size + myObj;    // The addition, keeping the result cached
size++;  // Another "thread" making a change
size = temp;   // The assignment, making the i++ disappear
```

As I said in my comment, use `size.addAndGet(myPersonalObject.getSize().get())` instead. Don't worry about the return value, you don't *need* to use it for anything.

Answer (score 4):

`AtomicLong` guarantees you the result of `get()` will be the "correct" content of the corresponding object (not something where one "half" of the value is an old value, and the other half is coming from a "new" value).

So, of course: that "internal" value of the AtomicLong object **can** very well change in your code. You first fetch its value, you add something, and write back that value.

In other words: when you are concerned that you always `set()` a **correct** value (whatever that means in your context) - then your implementation is not guaranteeing that!

Thus: you might want to use normal longs here - and instead of using `AtomicLong` your code provides the necessary synchronization to uphold the **contract** around this "counter".

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no reason to reinvent the wheel while using `java.util.concurrent.atomic`

Consider manual addition as you stated initially

**Approach #1 Java:**

```
public void test(Test myPersonalObject){
        this.size.set(this.size.get() + myPersonalObject.getSize().get());
}
```

Byte Code for this method:

```
0: aload_0
1: getfield #4 = Field Test.size(Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong;)
4: aload_0
5: getfield #4 = Field Test.size(Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong;)
8: invokevirtual #5 = Method java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong.get(()J)
11: aload_1
12: invokevirtual #6 = Method Test.getSize(()Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong;)
15: invokevirtual #5 = Method java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong.get(()J)
18: ladd
19: invokevirtual #7 = Method java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong.set((J)V)
22: return
```

And now `addAndGet` approach

**Approach #2 Java:**

```
public void test(Test myPersonalObject){
    this.size.addAndGet(myPersonalObject.getSize().get());
}
```

Byte Code produced:

```
0: aload_0
1: getfield #4 = Field Test.size(Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong;)
4: aload_1
5: invokevirtual #5 = Method Test.getSize(()Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong;)
8: invokevirtual #6 = Method java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong.get(()J)
11: invokevirtual #7 = Method java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong.addAndGet((J)J)
14: pop2
15: return
```

While `addAndGet` approach produces less byte code, **it also avoids the inconsistent increment** That happens because there is completely separate event of reading the `myPersonalObject.getSize()` - `Line 15` of 1-st approach and corresponding `line 8` of 2-nd. Which then followed by completely separate instruction of `ladd` and separate `set` (`lines 18-19` of first), comparing to `addAndGet` (`line 11` of second approach).

Now consider below diagram, let `myPersonalObject.getSize().get()` constantly **return 1** just for simplification of our example:

**Approach #1 set(get size + get 1)**

```
Thread 1       |    Thread 2      |     size
               |                  |     0
get 1          |    get 1         |     0
get size       |                  | ←   0
               |    get size      | ←   0
ladd size +1   |                  |     0
               |    ladd size +1  |     0
set back       |                  | →   1
               |    set back      | →   1
```

**Approach #2 addAndGet(get 1)**

```
Thread 1         |  Thread 2            |   size
                 |                      |   0
get 1            |                      |   0
                 |  get 1               |   0
addAndGet size+1 |                      | → 1
                 |  addAndGet size+1    | → 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a atomic statement :

```
this.size.set(this.size.get() + myPersonalObject.getSize().get());
```

`this.size.set`, `this.size.get()` and `myPersonalObject.getSize().get()` are atomic statements but chaining atomic statements will not combine and span their atomicity like a synchronized statement does :

```
synchronized(this){
  this.size.set(this.size.get() + myPersonalObject.getSize().get());
}
```

So in your example, `this.size.get()`  could be executed by a thread, the thread could be paused and another thread could execute :

```
this.size.set(this.size.get() + myPersonalObject.getSize().get());,
```

without being paused.
Then as the first thread is resumed, the `this.size.get()` value used may so not reflect the actual value of `this.size.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be a race condition. The atomic implementation guarantees that only one Thread has access to the field. It does not mean that it will reflect the value which may be changed by another Thread. For example `Thread 1` gets the value while doing that `Thread 2` gets the value afterwards but it's faster in executing the `set` method. Afterwards you don't have the expected result.

There is a [getAndSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#getAndSet(long)) method especially for these case. It uses the compare-and-swap mechanism to ensure that the retrieved value is actually the current value.

Answer (score 0):

@Kayaman gave the right, beaty answer, but also it's possible to make lock-free implementation with:

```
public void test(Object myPersonalObject){
    //do something

    long currentValue;
    long newValue;
    do {
        currentValue = this.size.get();
        newValue = currentValue + myPersonalObject.getSize().get();
    } while (!size.compareAndSet(currentValue, newValue));

    //do something
}
```

Comment: Which is incidentally what `AtomicLong.getAndUpdate(LongUnaryOperator)` does. However for a simple addition it's not necessary, as `addAndGet` does it in native code more efficiently.